# Spring MVC parent template model component

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, template-engine

I'm using Spring MVC 4 and I'm building a site with a template that requires several common components across pages, such as login status, cart status, etc. An example of controller function would be this:

```
@RequestMapping( path = {"/"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)    
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("listProducts", products );
        mav.addObject("listCategories",  menuCategoriasUtils.obtainCategories());
        return mav;
    }
```

What would be a good way/pattern to feed these elements that do not belong to the controller we are currently calling so we don't repeat over and over **unrelated** operations in every method of every controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a several approaches to show common data in views. One of them is using of `@ModelAttributte` annotation.

Lets say, you have user login, that needed to be shown on every page. Also, you have security service, where from you will get security information about current login. You have to create parent class for all controllers, that will add common information.

```
public class CommonController{

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addSecurityAttributes(Model model){
        User user = securityService.getCurrentUser();
        model.addAttribute("currentLogin", user.getLogin());

        //... add other attributes you need to show
    }

}
```

Note, that you don't need to mark `CommonController` with `@Controller` annotation. Because you'll never use it as controller directly. Other controllers have to be inherited from `CommonController`:

```
@Controller
public class ProductController extends CommonController{

    //... controller methods
}
```

Now you should do nothing to add `currentLogin` to model attributes. It will be added to every model automatically. And you can access user login in views:

```
...
<body>
   <span>Current login: ${currentLogin}</span>
</body>
```

More details about usage of `@ModelAttribute` annotation you can find [here in documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods).

Comment: Very useful answer. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I was looking for. Other solutions (mostly using Interceptors) don't work, this one does.